# How do I calculate and display the correct percentage?

Tags: c++

I am a C++ noob.

I am trying to work on this text-based game for school, and I am having trouble with displaying the correct percentage. I think this has to do with how I calculate it in the program, or I am screwing something up with the function.

I would be most grateful for some assistance. Cheers.

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double menu (float crew_count);

double calculatePct(float crew_count, float number_of_deaths)
{
    double percent = ((crew_count - number_of_deaths) / crew_count) * 100;
}

double welcome ()
{
    int crew_count;
    string backstory = "\nYou are in charge of a top-secret military mission, when your\nspace ship makes an emergency landing, on the largest moon of planet Gork.\nThe space ship is damaged. Oxygen levels begin to drop.\nHow many military personnel are on your ship?\nNumber of personnel: ";
    cout << backstory;
    cin >> crew_count;

    if (crew_count >= 1)
        menu(crew_count);
    else if (crew_count < 1)
        cout << "\nThere must be 1 or more members of the crew! Please enter a valid number!\n";
}

double menu (float crew_count)
{
    double percent;

    double main_option;
    cout << "\nChoose one:\n1. Attempt repairs on the ship.\n2. Request an emergency rescue from mission command.\n3. Break protocol and reveal the top-secret space ship's location,\nto the Russians on a nearby moon, asking for their assistance.\nYour choice: ";
         cin >> main_option;

    if (main_option == 1)
    {
        cout << "\nToxic material on the moon has corroded the launch gear, and the \nlaunch exploded!\n\nThere were no survivors.\n";
    }

    else if (main_option == 2)
    {
        cout << "\nThe oxygen was depleted before the rescue team arrived.\nThere were 4 people killed.\n";
        if (crew_count <=4)
            cout << "0% of crew members were rescued!\n";
        else
            float percent = calculatePct(crew_count, 4);
            cout << percent << "% of the crew was rescued.\n";
    }

    else if (main_option == 3)
    {
        cout << "\nThe Russians agree to send a rescue ship, but secretly attempt to hack into the ships systems remotely, which triggers an automatic shut down of all\ncommunications systems and locks all mission critical storage units, including\none of the storage unit that holds emergency oxygen tanks.\n\nOne quarter of all personnel are lost.\n";
    }

    else if (main_option != 1, 2, 3)
    {
        cout << "\nYou have been eaten by a Grue!\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Gork 1.0\nCreated by Cortez Phenix\nTo make selections, enter the number of each option!\n\n";

        int choice;
    cout << "What would you like to do?\n1. Play Game\n2. Exit\nYour Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
        welcome();
    else if (choice == 2)
        cout << "\nGoodbye!\n";
    else
        cout << "\nPlease choose 1 or 2.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Excuse me. I'm sure this post is hectic.

[IMAGE: At the bottom, you can see the queer number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8KZR.png)

Comment: Tabs dont form blocks in C++. You need braces. `float percent = calculatePct(crew_count, 4); cout << percent << "% of the crew was rescued.\n";` needs to be in a block.

Comment: I recommend always using the optional braces to people learning languages like C++ that use braces. If the braces are always in place, the bug is hard to miss.

Answer (score 3):

If we do some slight reformatting on parts of your code, it looks like this:

```
if (crew_count <=4)
    cout << "0% of crew members were rescued!\n";
else
    float percent = calculatePct(crew_count, 4);
cout << percent << "% of the crew was rescued.\n";
```

The value you print is *not* the value calculated by `calculatePct`, it's the indeterminate value of the `percent` variable defined earlier in the function.

In short: You forgot your curly-braces:

```
if (crew_count <=4)
    cout << "0% of crew members were rescued!\n";
else
{  // Note curly brace here
    float percent = calculatePct(crew_count, 4);
    cout << percent << "% of the crew was rescued.\n";
}  // And also here
```

I recommend you enable more verbose warnings, as the compiler should be able to detect that you use the uninitialized variable, as well as the new variable being initialized but not used.

Comment: Also, you have two different `percent` variables defined in that function.  If you get rid of the first (redundant) one then you would have got a compiler error which would have pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Additionally: `calculatePct` doesn't even `return` anything, even if it is non-void function. Hence, even invoking it, invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you mixed intergers and floats and void

1. `int crew_count` then you fed `double menu(float crew_count)`.
2. your menu function doesnt return anything its supossed to be void so does your welcome function
3. Also you `calculatePct` does not return the calculated percentage. Do that by adding `return percent;`

See if it helps